# Open blob objectURL in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, base64, blob

I want to open a PDF in a new tab in chrome browser (Chrome 56.0.2924.87, Ubuntu 14.04) using `window.open(fileObjectURL)` in javascript. I am creating the blob from base64 encoded data and do create an objectURL like this:

```
const fileObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
```

It works fine in latest Firefox browser. But in Chrome I can see that the new tab gets opened but then closed immediately. So I don't get any error in the console etc. 
The only way it works in Chrome now is to give the base64 data directly to the `window.open(fileBase64Data)` function. But I don't like the complete data being set in the url.

Maybe this is a safety issue with Chrome blocking opening of blobs?

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to open a PDF in a new tab and set the file name in the URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The cause is probably adblock extension (I had exactly the same problem).

Comment: Indeed, `uBlockOrigin` list called `easylist` (default one) has the rule `|blob:$popup` which blocks such new links with `blob` scheme, because (as stated by comment above in the list): `! Used with many websites to generate multiple popups` (if you know which sites used that trick, please tell me!)

Comment: The mentioned `|blob:$popup` was removed from EasyList in [this commit](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/commit/e797d6387be48555aeda27ee79477d17677a2bc7#diff-1b4e03b73bd3077b166228ad052f1c15a6c2f75907d0163030de451187dd36b2).

Answer (score 22):

You must open new window before you put blob url in window:

`let newWindow = window.open('/')`

Also you can use some another page like `/loading`, with loading indicator.

Then you need to wait newWindow loading, and you can push url of your blob file in this window:

```
newWindow.onload = () => {
    newWindow.location = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
```

Adblock extension don't block it.

I'm using it with AJAX and ES generators like this:

```
let openPDF = openFile();
openPDF.next();
axios.get('/pdf', params).then(file => {
  openPDF.next(file);
});

function* openFile() {
  let newWindow = window.open('/pages/loading');
  // get file after .next(file)
  let file = yield;
  // AJAX query can finish before window loaded,
  // So we need to check document.readyState, else listen event
  if (newWindow.document.readyState === 'complete') {
    openFileHelper(newWindow, file);
  } else {
    newWindow.onload = () => {
      openFileHelper(newWindow, file);
    };
  }
}

function openFileHelper(newWindow, file) {
  let blob = new Blob([file._data], {type: `${file._data.type}`});
  newWindow.location = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

Comment: I used
let newWindow = window.open('/');
  newWindow.onload = () => {
    newWindow.location.assign(blobURL);
  };
where blobURL is of type string.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Work around way to by pass adblocker.

coffeescript & jquery

```
$object = $("<object>")
$object.css
  position: 'fixed'
  top: 0
  left: 0
  bottom: 0
  right: 0
  width: '100%'
  height: '100%'
$object.attr 'type', 'application/pdf'
$object.attr 'data', fileObjectURL
new_window = window.open()
new_window.onload = ->
  $(new_window.document.body).append $object
```

Comment: This solution works for me in both Chrome and Firefox with uBlock Origin.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of the above solutions worked. The new window still gets blocked in production, in development it works. Only Chrome blocks, in Edge it's all fine.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30984352)

Answer (score 0):

Salaam

```
blob:http://***.***.***.**/392d72e4-4481-4843-b0d4-a753421c0433
```

Blobs are not blocked by chrome but are blocked by AdBlock extension
Either:

- Pause on this site
- Don't run on pages on this site
- Or Disable or Remove AdBlock Extension

[image: Don't run on pages on this site]

Answer (score 0):

In plain vanilly javascript (because I don't have jquery)

```
let newWindow = window.open('/file.html');
newWindow.onload = () => {
    var blobHtmlElement;
    blobHtmlElement = document.createElement('object');
    blobHtmlElement.style.position = 'fixed';
    blobHtmlElement.style.top = '0';
    blobHtmlElement.style.left = '0';
    blobHtmlElement.style.bottom = '0';
    blobHtmlElement.style.right = '0';
    blobHtmlElement.style.width = '100%';
    blobHtmlElement.style.height = '100%';
    blobHtmlElement.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf'); 
    blobHtmlElement.setAttribute('data', fileObjectURL);
    newWindow.document.title = 'my custom document title';
    newWindow.document.body.appendChild(blobHtmlElement);
};
```

`/file.html` is an almost empty html file, source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Tested in chrome & firefox (on 20/november/2019)

Comment: Doesn't work with Firefox 75. A warning "popup blocked" is displayed to user, and `newWindow` is `null` after calling `open()`.

Comment: work for me with a little change: 
```var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                let newWindow = window.open(fileURL);```

Answer (score -1):

I do not have Ad blocker. Looks like setting the blob type explicitly to application/pdf will solve this issue.

`const newBlob = new Blob([blobData], {type: "application/pdf"});`

Answer (score -2):

Done, I just added the **{type:"application/pdf"}** or you just add the any content type.