# AoR FileField prop target="_blank" does not work

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm trying to display the files attached to FileInput, provided by react-admin, in a new tab, instead of the current page. However it seems that the prop target="_blank" does not work properly. The document is not displayed in a new tab nor in the current one.

Code:

```
<FileInput
    label="File input"
    multiple={true}
>
    <FileField source="rawFile.preview" title="rawFile.name" target="_blank"/>
</FileInput>
```

Without the target prop the documents are correctly displayed in the current page.

**Is this a bug of FileInput component or am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out the problem was caused by AdBlock.

See this discussion: [Open blob objectURL in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283454/open-blob-objecturl-in-chrome)