# blob links are blocked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**My js Code**,  **My HTML File**

Simple input field for file

```js
const input= document.getElementById("file")

input.addEventListener("change",My)

 function My(e){

const file= e.target.files[0]

const blob= new Blob([file])

const url= URL.createObjectURL(blob)

console.log(url)

}
```

when  I create a Blob Link then it is successfull created blob link and also show the blob link content( only current tab or current browser window) but problem occur when I use this blob link to incognito mode then it give error, Blob Link are blocked and also occur this problem when refresh the current browser window.

How to tackle this problem?

Comment: Do you have extensions such as adblockers that are enabled in incognito? Can you share the full error message w/ the trace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open blob objectURL in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283454/open-blob-objecturl-in-chrome)

Comment: You may need to set the type in the `createObjectURL` or `new Blob` call.

Comment: after give the type, still same error

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*show the blob link content*". Are you trying to open the logged url in a new tab?

Comment: yes, I was try to open a new tab. but it is give this error

Comment: Don't do that, that's not what object urls are designed for.

Comment: The `blob` link is a temporary link, if you refresh the page it will lost. Although you can open it in a new tab of the same browser, but not support opening it in incognito mode.

Comment: The reason is in incognito mode or a different browser, the `blob` link will lose its `referer` or some cookie message.